# Java - Reentrant Lock, can't access newly created Condition

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, conditional-statements, reentrantlock

I have created a new Condition `chopstickFree` and in my `pickUpChopstick()` method, I am waiting for a lock on it but I can't get access to it at all.

Through debugging I have found that when it gets to the `chopstickFree.await()` line in the `pickUpChopstick()` method, it just pauses indefinitely

I don't understand? That code in the constructor was just an unsure attempt to get it working but either way, I have created a new condition, signaled to all that it is free, but I can't get a lock on it at all?

```
public class Chopstick {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private Condition chopstickFree = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition chopstickInUse = lock.newCondition();

    Chopstick() {
        lock.lock();
        chopstickFree.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }

    // Pick up chopstick
    public void pickUpChopstick() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();

        try {
            chopstickFree.await(); // ALWAYS PAUSES HERE INDEFINITELY
            chopstickInUse.signalAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // Release chopstick
    public void releaseChopstick() {
        lock.lock();
        chopstickFree.signal();
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: There is no exception just an indefinite pause

Comment: There is no chance that there are 2 different instances of `Chopstick` and the signal is happening to a different instance than the wait?

Comment: Hmm well there is an ArrayList <Chopstick>, two of those chopsticks were passed to another class, that class used its pickupLeftChopstick() method which in turn invoked the pickUpChopstick() method in the Chopstick class.

Comment: @mgibson - are you calling your `pickupChopstick` method in a thread separate from where your main logic is running? Otherwise you are locking yourself out completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Condition#signalAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signalAll%28%29) only signals threads that are currently in [`Condition#await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await%28%29) (or its friends), i.e. the signal isn't queued up for later calls.

You need another flag protected by the lock to correctly implement:

```
public class Chopstick {
  private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private final Condition chopstickFree = lock.newCondition();
  private volatile boolean isFree = true;

  Chopstick() { /* Nothing */ }

  // Pick up chopstick
  public void pickUpChopstick() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();

    try {
      while (!isFree) {
        chopstickFree.await();
      }
      isFree = false;
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  // Release chopstick
  public void releaseChopstick() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      isFree = true;
      chopstickFree.signal();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is a version using a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) that might be a little closer in intent to your original implementation:

```
public class Chopstick {
  private final Semaphore chopsticksAvailable = new Semaphore(1);

  Chopstick() {
    // Nothing
  }

  // Pick up chopstick
  public void pickUpChopstick() throws InterruptedException {
    chopsticksAvailable.acquire();
  }

  // Release chopstick
  public void releaseChopstick() {
    chopsticksAvailable.release();
  }
}
```